# childCount is always 0

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-engine

```
public void CreateEnemyObjectsToRoad( RoadPool roadpool, int numberOfEnemies, int enemyType )
    {
        enemy = new Transform[numberOfEnemies];
        enemyIndex = new int[numberOfEnemies];

        int arrayedEnemyObject = 0;
        int enemyObjectsDistance = 1;
        int randomSpawn = Random.Range( 0, 3 );

        for( int i = 0; i < road.Length; i++ )
        {
            int numberOfParents;
            Transform parentObject;

            if( randomSpawn == 0 )
            {
                parentObject = road[i].Find("SpawnPoint1");
            }
            else if( randomSpawn == 1 )
            {
                parentObject = road[i].Find("SpawnPoint2");
            }
            else if( randomSpawn == 2 )
            {
                parentObject = road[i].Find("SpawnPoint3");
            }
            else
            {
                parentObject = road[i].Find("SpawnPoint4");
            }

            numberOfParents = parentObject.childCount;

            Debug.Log(parentObject);
            Debug.Log(numberOfParents);

            for( int j = 0; j < numberOfParents && arrayedEnemyObject < numberOfEnemies; j++ )
            {
                Transform obj = roadpool.PullEnemyOjbectsFromPool(enemyType);
                obj.position = parentObject.GetChild(j).position;
                obj.gameObject.SetActive(true);

                enemy[j] = obj;
                enemyIndex[j] = enemyType;

                arrayedEnemyObject++;
            }
        }
    }
```

I am trying to spawn enemy to random points of my infinite road. I created parent with Transform.Find it works, but I have to count parents when I try to count it not works, my numberOfParents variable is always zero.

Debug.Log 
[image: My Debug.Log]

Road Prefab 
[image: My Road Prefab]

Comment: yes. ParentObject.position is works well but numberOfParents is not working always 0, why it is not counting

Comment: Have you used the debugger? Why do you have an `else`? Since `randomSpawn` must always be between 0 and 2  there is no way that you get into the `else`. So either remove it, change to `Random.Range( 0, 4)` or throw an exeption in the `else`.

Comment: I changed thanks, but it is not solution of my problem.

Comment: I know, that's why it's a  comment. I'm not familiar with Unity3D, so hopefully someone else can help you.

Comment: Are you instantiating the SpawnPoint1, etc at run time? If so it's "SpawnPoint1(clone)". Also it's much easier doing tags and layer names as opposed to Finding by name alone. In the inspector go to Tag, and give it a unique tag name. After then you can find objects with the tag name (there are integral functions). Finding the number of objects with the specific tag/layer name should be easy.

Comment: Your code doesn't show anything modifying the parentObject.  Where in your code are you calculating `parentObject.childCount?  How do children get added to the parent?  Please post that code as well.

Comment: I edited my post, you can see my prefab and childs.

Comment: I'm a bit confused by your naming and its making this hard to figure out. The line "numberOfParents = parentObject.childCount;" seems to say: number of parents is equal to the number of children.  Is this possibly the source of the bug? Or should that variable jsut be called "numberOfChildren"?

Answer (score 0):

Are you instantiating the SpawnPoint1, etc at run time? If so it's "SpawnPoint1(clone)". Also it's much easier doing tags and layer names as opposed to Finding by name alone. In the inspector go to Tag, and give it a unique tag name. After then you can find objects with the tag name (there are integral functions). Finding the number of objects with the specific tag/layer name should be easy. Just tag the children as "spawnChild" then do the following:

```
 var childCount : int = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("spawnChild").Length;
```

Also use Debug.Log to get the number counts in each of your if/then's. You should ideally use a case statement instead of an if/then but i suppose it doesn't matter. Also you may want to initialize your Transform or int variables outside of the for loop.

Also you may want to do childCount on the transform not on the GameObject, for example:

```
parentObject.transform.childCount
```

or you can

```
parentObject = road[i].Find("SpawnPoint1").transform;
```

Or you should probably make `GameObject parentObject;` vs. a `Transform parentObject;`. Then you can find grab the transform off of the GameObject.

Comment: you can see my debug.log numbercount is always 0, but spawnpoints are works well

Comment: Maybe parentObject.transform.childCount?

Comment: May I suggest the tag names then. Use tag names in lieu of childCount. Then you can do a find and see how  many exist.

Comment: try GameObject.Find("SpawnPoint1").transform.childCount; and output to Debug.Log. I'm curious to see if road[i] isn't finding properly.

Comment: still zero. I dont understand why why why

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75863/discussion-between-kal-drogo-and-amitapollo).